# In JGit, is calling DiffFormatter.format(DiffEntry) for a single DiffEntry supposed to give you differences for the entire commit?

Tags: java, git, diff, jgit

When I iterate through DiffEntrys for differences between the work area and the head commit, it looks like each DiffEntry represents a file. However, when I call formatter.format(DiffEntry), I get a string representing all the differences between the work area and the head commit.  Not just the file that the DiffEntry is associated with.  Is that how it supposed to work?  How can I get the differences for just the one file that the DiffEntry is associated with?  Will I need to parse the string myself?

```
import org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffFormatter;
import org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffEntry;
```

...

```
    repository=m_git.getRepository();
    outputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    headObjectId=repository.resolve(Constants.HEAD);
    revWalk!=new RevWalk(repository);
    headRevCommit=revWalk.parseCommit(headObjectId);`
    
    // Get a list of diffs between the working tree and head commit
    formatter = new DiffFormatter(outputStream);
    formatter.setRepository(repository);
    commitTreeIterator = prepareTreeParser(headRevCommit);
    workTreeIterator = new FileTreeIterator(repository);
    diffEntries = formatter.scan(commitTreeIterator, workTreeIterator);
    while (diffIter.hasNext()) {  
   
        // Capture all the  differences into a string
        entry=cast(DiffEntry,diffIter.next());
        formatter.format(entry);
        x=outputStream.toString();
        
        // x has diffs for all files and not just the file this DiffEntry represents!
        System.out.println(entry.getNewPath());
        System.out.println(x); 
   }
```

It even states in documentation that it formats a patch script for one file entry, so I am not understanding why I am getting all the file entries in a single string: https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/5.8.1.202007141445-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/diff/DiffFormatter.html#format-org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffEntry-

Comment: `formatter.format` appends the diff of the given `DiffEntry` to the output stream That's probably why you see output like `diff 1\ndiff 1\ndiff2\ndiff 1\ndiff 2\ diff3\n...`. Either use a new formatter for each call to `formatter.format`, or reset the output stream after each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rüdiger Herrmann pointed out, my code is appending each DiffEntry to the OutputStream.  Since I am using a ByteArrayOutputStream, I can call ByteArrayOutputStream.reset() between entries so that I only get a single DiffEntry for each time I call ByteOutputStream.toString().

In my code sample, it would look like this:

```
while (diffIter.hasNext()) {  

    // Capture all the  differences into a string
    entry=cast(DiffEntry,diffIter.next());
    formatter.format(entry);
    x=outputStream.toString();
    outputStream.reset(); 
    
    // x has diffs for all files and not just the file this DiffEntry represents!
    System.out.println(entry.getNewPath());
    System.out.println(x); 
}
```